# General way of solving a system 3rd order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a simpler example of four flows: $u(t),v(t),p(t),q(t)$; their dynamics is given as

$$\frac{d^3q(t)}{dt^3} = -p(t)$$
$$\frac{d^3p(t)}{dt^3} = -q(t)$$

$$\frac{du(t)}{dt} = -v(t) + q(t)$$
$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt} = u(t) + p(t)$$

how should I approach this problem

Comment: The standard trick is to substitute new variables for the derivatives. e.g., let $q_1(t) = q'(t)$, $q_2(t) = q''(t)$ and so on.  Then you have a linear system of first-order equations. For example,
$\frac{d^3q(t)}{dt^3} = -p(t)$ becomes $\frac{d q(t)}{dt} = q_1(t)$, $\frac{d q_1(t)}{dt} = q_2(t)$, $\frac{d q_2(t)}{dt} = -p(t)$.  Then you can use whatever you know about solving first-order systems.